# In server it showes an error like [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-models, django-views, aws-serverless

When run in server it shows an error like [Errno 5] Input/output error,but it is work on localhost,can you solve this issue

urls.py

```
    url(r'followpopularnewsprovider/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', csrf_exempt(views.GetMobilefollowpopularnewsproviderTest), name='popularprovider'),
```

views.py

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
"""Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"""
columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
return [
    dict(zip(columns, row))
    for row in cursor.fetchall()
]

def GetMobilefollowpopularnewsproviderTest(request,user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    queryset = cursor.execute("select crawl_newsproviders.id,crawl_newsproviders.provider,crawl_providers.url,crawl_providers.region, crawl_providers.image,crawl_providers.description,crawl_providers.followers,crawl_providers.slug,crawl_providers.created_time,crawl_providers.publish,1 as status from crawl_providers join  accounts_followprovider on crawl_providers.id=accounts_followprovider.provider_id where accounts_followprovider.user_id='%s' union select crawl_providers.id,crawl_providers.provider,crawl_providers.url,crawl_providers.region, crawl_providers.image,crawl_providers.description,crawl_providers.followers,crawl_providers.slug,crawl_providers.created_time,crawl_providers.publish,0 from crawl_providers where crawl_providers.provider not in(select crawl_providers.provider as id from crawl_providers join  accounts_followprovider on crawl_providers.id=accounts_followprovider.provider_id where accounts_followprovider.user_id='%s');"%(user_id,user_id))
    dict = {}
    dict = dictfetchall(cursor)
    print(dict)
    context = {
        'posts': dict
    }
    cursor.close()
    return JsonResponse(context)
return HttpResponse(status=201)
```

Comment: It doesnt sound like a  python/django error. Can you give more detail about the error please.

Comment: Btw I cant help asking, why on earth are you dealing with sql while using django? Why dont you use django orm?

Comment: when i close the server terminal ,the api does not working ,here the deployed server act as the localhost server,how to solve this server issue.